# Error code in importing multiple csv files from certain folder using matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am really a newbie in matlab programming. I have a problem in coding to import multiple csv files into one from certain folder:

[image: my error]

This is my code:

```
%% Importing multiple CSV files

myDir = uigetdir; %gets directory
myFiles = dir(fullfile(myDir,'*.csv')); %gets all csv files in struct
for k = 1:length(myFiles)
    data{k} = csvread(myFiles{k});
end
```

I use the code uigetdir in order to be able to select data from any folder, because I try to make an automation program so it would be flexible to use by others. The code that I run only look for the directory and shows the list, but not for merging the csv files into one and read it in "import data". I want it to be merged and read as one file.
My merged file should look like this with semicolon delimited and consist of 47 csv files merged together (this picture is one of the csv file I have):
[my merged file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAisf.png)

I have been working for it a whole day but I find always error code. Please help me :(. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: would you mind providing some sample content for your csv file just to inform what function to use? Can you also include your code so far?  Are you trying to combine the content of the csv files? Your first sentence is unclear.

Comment: Hi @PhilipBrack I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: does your csvread work for 1 file?

Comment: No, it should work for 47 files that I have @PhilipBrack

Comment: The OP is creating the same question over and over. Just look at his profile activity. Nevertheless, he is pretending full working code by replying with comments and adding more and more questions.

Comment: I am sorry @TommasoBelluzzo because I am a newbie in matlab programming. I got already an answer for csv file. I also have modified the answer for xls in the same structure for merging csv files, but I still got an error. That's why I ask in this forum. I am sorry if this bothers you. And sorry again, I am a woman.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you're attempting to reference `myFiles` as a cell array when it is not. The output of [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.htm) is a structure, which cannot be indexed like a cell array.

You want to do something like the following:

```
for k = 1:numel(myFiles)
    filepath = fullfile(myFiles(k).folder, myFiles(k).name);
    data{k} = csvread(filepath);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @excaza However I still got an error message. If I want to use semicolon delimited form, how to adjust it in my codes? Thank you

Comment: @KasihDitaningtyas use [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).